# Why is the Warhammer Fantasy species "Cold One" named as such?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy

The Warhammer Fantasy universe has a raptor like species called "Cold one", used as mounts by Lizardmen and Dark Elves. Why are the creatures called "Cold one"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is unrelated to board game expertise, and should instead be asked on [scifi.se].

Comment: Hum? Isn't Warhammer is a tabletop miniature game rather than sci-fi media?

Comment: Could it be a reference to cold-bloodness?

Comment: Warhammer is a multimedia franchise based on a miniatures wargame. It has since spun off into novels, video games, and other media, just like Magic: The Gathering has. While this question would also be appropriate on SciFi/Fantasy SE, I think that it, and other lore questions about tabletop games, are on topic and should remain open.

Comment: Its a question of "fluff", which for many roleplay gamers is an important part. 
And yes, this is about fantasy and not about sci-fi in any way at all. Cold Ones are found in Warhammer Fantasy, not in Warhammer 40k.

Comment: I wish there was  a "vote not to close" option.. I've often wondered the answer to this question myself.

Comment: @aslum A preemptive "vote not to close" button doesn't exist, although you can [sort of do that with the review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134673/191265). The difficulty of this is by design. The best thing you can do if you want this to stay open is to cast a reopen vote if this gets closed.

Answer (score 3):

2 reasons that I could find:

- It is a reference to the people that use them. Only cold-blooded people can   ride them without a problem
- They see all warm-blooded things as prey, so they are the cold ones and the enemy the warm ones

Source: http://warhammerfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Cold_Ones

Comment: This doesn't quite work, as Dark Elves are not cold-blooded (cold hearted, yes, but not cold blooded)